# Redux Toolkit and React Query in one project

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-query

I have a quick question about React: is it bad to use both Redux Toolkit and React Query in one project?

The thing is, I know a bit about both. I am familiar with stuff related to fetching data and pagination with React Query. Now, I think stuff like that can also be done with Redux Toolkit (Redux Toolkit Query more specifically, correct me if I'm wrong) but I have no experience with that. On the other hand, I like using RTK for state management but do not have much experience doing that with RQ (using RQ mutators).

So, is it bad if I use both in the same project, and rely on RQ for some stuff like pagination and on RTK for state management, or should I just go for one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with react-query, and you are using Redux Toolkit, you might want to check out RTK-Query which is similar to react-query but integrates directly with redux.

Comment: I will make sure to check it out.